# Composer php install

Tags: php, composer

Composer php. Знаком с этой штукой почти недавно. Не могу нормально установить. Скачал composer.phar файл и даю команду `php composer.phar install` отвечает что типа не нашел какой-то файл composer.json (а его рядом нет папка пуста). Откуда его взять? Зачем он нужен? Пытаюсь установить laravel. На оф. сайте написано такая команда для установки `composer require laravel/horizon` при вводе этого пишет что команда `composer` не опознана. Что делать? Есть ли детальный мануал?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Comment: @madfan41k на русском нету ли?

Comment: А самому найти что не ? https://www.hostinger.com.ua/rukovodstva/kak-ustanovit-composer

Answer (score 1):

**Если Вы используете Linux** (Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS и т.д):

1) Обновите библиотеки командой

```
sudo apt-get update
```

2) Установите зависимости командой

```
sudo apt-get install curl git
```

3) Загрузите установщик composer

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', '/tmp/composer-setup.php');"
```

4) Проверьте хеш файла

```
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', '/tmp/composer-setup.php') === 'sha_384_string') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('/tmp/composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
```

Где sha_384_string нужно взять отсюда: https://composer.github.io/pubkeys.html

5) Если напишет "Installer verified", то можно запустить инсталяцию (на самом деле можно пропустить пункт 4, работать будет и без него, но проверить файл всё же стоит)

```
sudo php /tmp/composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

6) Теперь проверим установку следующей командой

```
composer --version
```

Если вывело версию композера - всё ок. Нет - смотрим в пункт 1 и далее по списку.

7) Если всё ок - удаляем временный файл

```
rm /tmp/composer-setup.php
```

---

**Если Вы используете Windows** (серьёзно?):

1) Скачать установщик: https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

2) Установить

3) ...

4) PROFIT!